# Quantum gate that takes two vectors and negates projection of the first within the second?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

Is it possible to construct a quantum operation $U$ that performs

$$U(|a\rangle \otimes |b\rangle) = |a\rangle \otimes \left( \text{perp}_a |b\rangle - \text{proj}_a |b\rangle \right)$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are quantum states (kets), $\text{proj}_x y$ is the projection of $y$ onto $x$, and $\text{perp}_x y$ is the component of $y$ perpendicular to $x$ (i.e. $y - \text{proj}_x y$).

In other words, $U$ is an operation where the first argument directly determines an eigenvector of a sub-operation applied to the second argument. We want applying $U$ to $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ to apply the sub-operation $V = I - 2|a\rangle \langle a|$ to just $|b\rangle$.

$$U(|a\rangle \otimes |b\rangle) = |a\rangle \otimes \left((I - 2 |a\rangle \langle a|) \cdot |b\rangle \right)$$

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is perp? What does a,b refer to? Are they kets?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Better now?

Comment: Yes, especially the part after "in other words".  There, you immediately see that it is not a linear map, so you can answer the question in one line.  (The initial formula somehow obfuscates what actually happens.)

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it's not possible. The operation isn't linear.

The operation seems naively okay when you're thinking of $a$ as pure and independent. In that case the operation on $b$ is certainly reversible, which is good. And, for any given $a$, the operation is equivalent to some *specific* operation that's allowed. But now consider what happens when $a$ is entangled with $b$. Does the mixed state of $b$ get reflected through the mixed state of $a$? How does that make *any* sense in terms of the components of the superposition? There's trouble lurking here.

More tellingly, constructing the operation out of its action on each vector of a basis doesn't work. For example, by going over the computational basis states, we see that the operation negates the $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ states while leaving the other two alone:

$$
\begin{align}
|0\rangle, |0\rangle &\rightarrow |0\rangle, -|0\rangle\\
|0\rangle, |1\rangle &\rightarrow |0\rangle, |1\rangle\\
|1\rangle, |0\rangle &\rightarrow |1\rangle, |0\rangle\\
|1\rangle, |1\rangle &\rightarrow |1\rangle, -|1\rangle
\end{align}
$$

But we need $U(|+\rangle,|0\rangle)$ to return $|+\rangle,-|1\rangle$. (When you negate the $|+\rangle$ component of $|0\rangle$ you end up with $-|1\rangle$.) And if $U$ just negates $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ then it doesn't return what we want; it returns $|-\rangle,|0\rangle$ instead. We flipped the wrong input! The operation just isn't generalizing the way it should.

Another way to convince yourself the operation can't work is to notice that its definition multiplies two inputs together (when projecting $a$ onto $b$). Linear operations never multiply their inputs.

Yet other reasons it can't work:

- When $a$ is part of a singlet state, its decomposition into eigenvectors for $U$ is ambiguous. Depending on how you resolve the ambiguity, you violate monogamy of entanglement or create FTL communication.
- You can use $U$ to exponentially ramp up the rotation used in Grover search, by leap-frogging new states over previous intermediate states. You'd finish after $O(\lg n)$ queries, but we *know* at least $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ queries are required for this problem.
- $U$ negates four linearly independent vectors ($|00\rangle$, $|11\rangle$, $|++\rangle$, and $|--\rangle$). That indicates its -1 eigenspace spans four dimensions: the whole input space. But it also leaves four linearly independent vectors alone ($|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$, $|-+\rangle$, and $|+-\rangle$). So its +1 eigenspace would also span the whole input space. Not good.